# Looking for a specific FTP server

Tags: ftp, ubuntu, scripting

Hey I am looking for an FTPD that I can run on ubuntu 10.04 that I can automate user creation and deletion via php scripts.  I also need to be able to point the users to a specific ftp directory instead of just their home.  I have looked into Proftpd and vsftpd but after the basic docs I am not really finding what I need.

Thank you guys

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Proftpd for this is really easy since proftpd can use Mysql as a source for authentication, and manipulating a database in PHP is trivial.  Check out the [Proftpd SQL mini-howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html).  Ignore the section about how to compile, just install the `proftpd-mod-mysql` or `proftpd-mod-pgsql` package.

Comment: Can you point all users of proftpd to a specific directory, Currently all users I have point to their own ~/

Comment: If you are using the SQL backend you can point the user at any directory you like.  Just set the value of the 'home' field to the directory you want them to access

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.worldlingo.com/ma/enwiki/en/XY_problem).

If you want visitors to a PHP site to be able to register and then upload and download files, I would do the whole job in PHP without involving FTP. PHP can support file upload and download over HTTP. It can also create directories per registered user if that is what is required or it can track ownership internally (in terms of registered user) regardless of the Linux ownership of the file.

Comment: -1, their may be a legitimation reason for ftp.  Perhaps he requires compatibility with some client/program that only supports ftp.  Perhaps he doesn't want to expend the lots of time it will take to replicate FTP-like behavior with a PHP application.  It seems kind of silly to reinvent a file transfer program in PHP when they already exist.

Comment: +1 for proposing a well reasoned alternative. Although the question asks about ftp servers, the use-case described does not necessarily require ftp, and it may help the OP to learn about alternatives.